# i want to validate the mobile number in grails and the mobile number must start with specific digit like 9

Tags: grails

I want to check the mobile number validation in grails??the mobile number must start with the first specific digit 9.if it starts with any other number then user must get the message to enter the number starting with 9 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `matches` constraints for this requirement like:

```
class Mobi {

long mobileNo

static constraints = {
mobileNo(blank:false, matches:"9[0-9]{10}")
 }
}
```

And then set your message in `message.properties`.

Comment: I also want to check the DOB  and validate it ..the month should not be greater than 12 and month should not exceed 31..can you help me?

Comment: Rewat, please ask a new stackoverflow question for that. Better still, search for an existing one! (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087649/validating-date-format-inside-a-groovy-controller, also read the javadoc for `SimpleDateFormat` - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)